# concatenate features with identical ID in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, concatenation

I have tables that have many features, and these features can have the same ID.

How can I check each for ID, then concatenate identical ID features in one row?

For example, here's an example of a simple table stored in a dataframe [several features and one ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTMtU.png) and the output will concatenate all features that have same ID and put them as new features and for IDs that don't have other features will be zero value as in this table:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, You can use:

```
dfx=df.groupby('ID').agg(list)
max_list_lenght=len(dfx.max()[0])
final=pd.DataFrame(dfx.apply(lambda x: [x[i][j] if len(x[i]) > j else 0 for j in range(0,max_list_lenght) for i in dfx.columns],axis=1).tolist(), index=dfx.index)
final.columns=['dat' + str(i) for i in range(1,len(final.columns) + 1)]
```

**Output**:

```
    dat1  dat2  dat3  dat4  dat5  dat6
ID                                    
1      9     3     6     5     7     7
2      5     5     5     6     5     5
3      3     0     5     0     0     0
```

Comment: thanks, your code is working. However, how I can extend the code to be applied on all features since I have thousands of features.

Comment: Please add a sample of your expected output with **multiple features** to the question.

Comment: I updated the question, and I added figure of results on three features. I hope you can help me.

Comment: wait, the expected outputs do not match. i'm working on it :)

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer? is the output correct?

Comment: order of features aren't correct

Comment: Okey, i edited the answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

`join` is what you need. And specify `how='outer'` if you dont want to lose any of row.

```
df1.set_index('ID').join(df2.set_index('ID'), how='outer')
```